# Why doesn't this if statement work for checking if an array has a specific number?

Tags: python, arrays, list, int

Given an int array length 2, return True if it contains a 2 or a 3. I can't use loops. Most of the test cases work except:

```
has23([4, 5]) --> False (my code returns True)
has23([7, 7]) --> False (my code returns True)
has23([9, 5]) --> False (my code returns True)
```

My code:

```
def has23(nums):
  if 2 or 3 in nums[0:1]:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `if` condition

```py
if 2 or 3 in nums[0:1]
```

Your condition will return `True` if either of `2` or `3 in nums[0:1]` evaluates to `True`. In which case, `2` will always evaluate to True and, hence, your code returns `True` every time.

**Side Note:**
This condition has another problem. It will **only** check the first element of array (not the complete array). `nums[0:1]` returns elements starting from the 0th index and ending before the 1st index (1st index excluded). So, in this case, it will only return the first element.

Change it to something like this:

```py
if 2 in nums or 3 in nums:
```

This condition will return `True` if either `2 in nums` or `3 in nums` evaluates to `True` (searching the element in whole list)

Answer (score 0):

`in` binds more tightly than `or`, so the statement `2 or 3 in nums[0:1]` is equivalent to `2 or (3 in nums[0:1])`. As `or` will short circuit, and `2` is always true, the second half is never evaluated, and the if statement always evaluates to true.

The comparison could be re-written as `3 in nums or 4 in nums` which is equivalent to `(3 in nums) or (4 in nums)`.

The construct:

```
if foo:
  return True
else:
  return False
```

Where foo is a boolean value is equivalent to:

```
return foo
```

Putting these together the function can be re-written as

```
def has23(nums):
    return 2 in nums or 3 in nums
```

Comment: Important to note, even if `or` bound more tightly, the expression still wouldn't work like the OP assumed it would